# export array content to csv row with php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to export an array to csv, but my csv contains only one row with many fields (columns). I want to achieve to export into rows my data.
My data looks like when I dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "something1" [1]=> string(18) "something2" }
```

here is the php code: ($names is my array)

```
$list = array ($names);
$fp = fopen('download.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: now looks like:
[image]
how to achieve this:[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108157/php-array-to-csv)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I updated my question :) @u_mulder

Comment: you mean, you will have one column with multiple rows ?

Comment: yes @Ravi, Acieve to have multiple rows from array than one row with multiple columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to put the `$names` into an array to accomplish what you want.

```
$fp = fopen('download.csv', 'w');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    fputcsv($fp, [$name]);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @almostokey I've updated it to reflect your desired outcome.