# Force download with php

Tags: php, download

I'm preparing a CSV file to download.

I know I'm nearly there as the link at the end of this code produces the right result. What I need to do and don't understand why it doesn't work, is create the downloaded file programmtically (using an example from `http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php`). If I omit `ob_start()` I get "Headers already sent" error, if I include them nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$filename = 'export.csv';
$data = fopen($filename, 'w');
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  fputcsv($data, $row);
}  
fclose($data);

if (file_exists($filename)) {
  ob_start();
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

    readfile($filename);

  ob_get_clean();
}
```

The output file is produced fine, I can see it on the server and it downloads using a link as valid CSV correctly produced. It's purely prompting the download that is not happening.

Comment: Pass the full path to the $filename like $filename = 'http://demo.com/files/export.csv'

Comment: try to add die() function after ob_get_clean()

Comment: Thanks for the comment but die(), exit() just stops things with no result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108157/php-array-to-csv)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I've read that question and responses. The production of the CSV is not the issue, it's forcing the download that's not working here.