# Setting encoding, newline, linebreaks, end-of-line (EOL) in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, newline, line-breaks, eol

For example, when I create a new file:

```
$message = "Hello!";    
$fh = fopen(index.html, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $message);
fclose($fh);
```

How can I set it's encoding(utf-8 or shift-jis or euc-jp) and linebreaks(LF or CR+LF or CR) in PHP?

Answer (score 4):

The encoding of a string literal should match the encoding of the source file, to convert between encodings you could use [iconv](http://uk.php.net/iconv).

```
$utf8=iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $message);
```

Line breaks are entirely up to you. You could use the [PHP_EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-phpeol) constant, or if you think you might need to vary the type of line break, store the desired sequence in a variable and configure it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To add carriage returns and linefeeds use the special characters \r and \n. So:

```
$message = "Hello!\r\n";
```