# Php assigning multiple strings to a single variable

Tags: php, string, variable-assignment, multiline

Is there a cleaner way to assign multiple strings to a single variable in php?

I current do like [this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pcx-dvr)

```
<?php
$myStr = '';

$myStr .= 'John';
$myStr .= '<br>';
$myStr .= 'Paul';
$myStr .= '<br>';
$myStr .= 'Ringo';

echo $myStr;
?>
```

I also use [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/heredoc). But are there other ways?

Comment: whats wrong in this ?  its perfectly fine

Comment: `$myStr = 'John'.'<br>'.'Paul'.'<br>'.'Ringo';`

Comment: This simple example can be reduced to a one liner, but maybe you should provide more context to your question.

Comment: @Antony why not like `$myStr = 'John <br> Paul <br> Ringo';` :P

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Because it would be so obvious that I assume these are some kind of variables containing different strings that are not hard-coded in the script.

Comment: Later if you want to get particular value out of string. Then you will have to explode it etc.. So why dont you use array and push new elements to it? It will be easy to manipulate.

Comment: Think i'll go with the array method. Looks cleaner and easy to manage.

Comment: @Antony if there are variables then why not `$myStr = "$name <br /> Paul <br /> Ringo";`?

Comment: cleaner is not always better way .... if i were you i would use string concatenation method

Answer (score 4):

If you have to concatenate lot of data, it may be a good idea to use `arrays`. **It's cleaner** (not necessarily more memory efficient).

```
$items = array('Hello', 'How', 'Are', 'You?');
echo implode(' ', $items);
```

Comment: A memory consuming and [slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502654/php-many-concats-or-one-implode) idea.

Comment: at least it answer the question in not an ironic way

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes, sure. It depends on situation. There might be even a special class for OP's needs.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by `array` and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like below

```
$names = array('John', 'Paul', 'Ringo');
$myStr = implode("<br>", $array);
echo $myStr;
```

Comment: 2 DownVoter. Please, be more constructive. Supply downvotes with comments.