# Heredoc: what does the commonly used 'EOT' actually mean?

Tags: php, heredoc

PHP's [Heredoc examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) always seem to use EOT (and sometimes EOD) as the seperating string, while it is actually possible to use any string here. This works:

```
$mystring = <<<EOT
     Foo
     Bar
     Baz
EOT;
```

While this works as well:

```
$mystring = <<<MONKIES
     Foo
     Bar
     Baz
MONKIES;
```

**Does EOT actually stand for something and if so, what?**

Comment: "End of text" or maybe "End of tape" (from the old days when using tapes for data storage was standard)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

​It stands for "End Of Text".​

Comment: Would *beginning* of text not be a lot more logical? :) Also, what does EOD stand for, then?

Comment: No, since it marks the end. What you see at the top is a signal to continue until EOT is spotted. EOD is End of Data.

Answer (score 17):

Actually `end of text` would be `ETX` – `EOT` is `end of transmission`.

Reference: [ASCII - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart)

Comment: @NisseEngström https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-tape redirect to end-of-file and is `EOF`.

Answer (score 10):

## Short answer

*Probably* **E**nd **O**f **T**ext and **E**nd **O**f **D**ata.

## Long answer

The only ones who can tell you definitively what the acronyms mean are the authors of the original (and current) documentation. But based on an [early version of the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20010215003853/http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) which mentions "here doc **text**", I think one could plausibly assume that **EOT** is intended to mean End of **Text**.

Similarly, the [current documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) makes a comparison between Nowdocs and SGML `<![CDATA[ ]]>` sections, so a reasonable assumption would be that **EOD** stands for End Of **Data**.

Sure, there's a definition of EOT in the [ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), but that refers to a *single* character `04`<sub><sub>16</sub></sub> and this definition doesn't transfer to anything else unless explicitly stated. About the only thing we can learn from the ASCII standard in this regard is the encoding of the *three* letters `E`, `O` and `T`.

This is all guesswork of course, but these are the only sensible explanations I can think of.
Personally, I prefer to avoid the whole issue by using a single underscore (`<<<_`).

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to go for the TRON reference and use 'EOL' (End of Line).

Comment: This is funny.  I'd mark this as favorite if I could. :D