# Multi-line string literals in PHP

Tags: php, string

Consider:

```
$xml = "l";
$xml = "vv";

echo $xml;
```

This will echo `vv`. Why and how can I do multi-line string literals for things like [SimpleXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimpleXML), etc.?

Comment: Do you want it to echo "l" followed by "vv" on the next line?

Comment: Look up `concatenation`.  That's what it's called when you put together strings.

Comment: @haywire By being the first and helpful result on Google.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Well,

```
$xml = "l
vv";
```

Works.

You can also use the following:

```
$xml = "l\nvv";
```

or

```
$xml = <<<XML
l
vv
XML;
```

---

### Edit based on comment:

You can concatenate strings using the `.=` operator.

```
$str = "Hello";
$str .= " World";
echo $str; //Will echo out "Hello World";
```

Comment: You forgot if I have loops or MySQL while loops between. Thanks

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Ummm... What?

Comment: Example. *while($rc=mysql_fetch_array($adviews))
{
$xml.="<set name='".$rc["date"]."' value='1' hoverText='".$rc["date"]."'/>";
}
$xml.="</graph>";*

Comment: IE. String and after a few lines a Loop and then continue. Building the string up.

Comment: Thanks. You need to include .= too

Comment: @SecondRikudo, Since normal quotes can be expanded on multiple lines already, [Why bother](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848945/best-practices-working-with-long-multiline-strings-in-php/1848974#comment47080440_1848974) with heredocs and nowdocs at all?

Comment: @Pacerier You don't need to escape quotes inside of a heredoc.

Comment: @SecondRikudo, Wait, he's asking for a multi-line string right? What has escaping got to do with this?

Comment: @Pacerier You asked why we need to bother with heredoc over quotes. That's why. Both are options for multiline strings.

Comment: Given that the topic is *multi-line* the `.=` operator example might be more relevant as `$str = "Line 1\n";  $str .= "Line 2\n";`  Or incorporating Ryan's answer: `$str = "Line 1" . PHP_EOL;  $str .= "Line 2" . PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 308):

PHP has Heredoc and Nowdoc strings, which are the best way to handle multiline strings in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
$var is replaced automatically.
EOD;
```

A Nowdoc is like a Heredoc, but it doesn't replace variables.

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
$var is NOT replaced in a nowdoc.
EOD;
```

You don't have to use "`EOD`" as your start/end identifier; it can be any string you want.

**Beware indentation.** Prior to PHP 7.3, the end identifier `EOD` must not be indented *at all* or PHP won't acknowledge it. In PHP 7.3 and higher, `EOD` may be indented by spaces or tabs, in which case the indentation will be stripped from all lines in the heredoc/nowdoc string.

Comment: Upvoted because I always forget about the indentation.

Comment: UGH! The indentation YES!!

Comment: PHP now allows the end token to be indented, if your heredoc contents are indented the same way. The amount of whitespace before the end token will be removed from the start of every heredoc line as well.

Comment: **Note:** As of Nov 2021, even though PHP 7.3 allows EOD indentation, many text/code editors will fail to recognize it as valid and will instead show syntax warnings or broken code highlighting. Relevant Notepad++ issue: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5264

Comment: EOD, EOT, ABC, etc., they're all arbitrary and can be anything like the answer says, for anyone wondering when to use EOD and EOT :)

Answer (score 17):

Not sure how it stacks up performance-wise, but for places where it doesn't really matter, I like this format because I can be sure it is using \r\n (CRLF) and not whatever format my PHP file happens to be saved in.

```
$text="line1\r\n" .
      "line2\r\n" .
      "line3\r\n";
```

It also lets me indent however I want.

Answer (score 13):

```
$xml="l" . PHP_EOL;
$xml.="vv";
echo $xml;
```

Will echo:

```
l
vv
```

Documentation on [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

Comment: Is there a way to mark answers? I've always thought you could only do that on questions. @TheBlackBenzKid

Comment: I meant I gave him a plus +1 as I repped him up.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid "faved" ;)

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), you can collect everything that is being outputted/echoed and store it in a variable.

```
<?php
ob_start(); 

?>line1
line2
line3<?php 

$xml = ob_get_clean();
```

Please note that output buffering might not be the best solution in terms of performance and code cleanliness for this exact case but worth leaving it here for reference.

Answer (score 9):

PHP has two inbuilt methods HEREDOC and NOWDOC to handle multiline strings. HEREDOC has also it syntax <<<.

Here is the example of multiline PHP string by using HEREDOC,

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT
My name is BB. I am printing some Text.
Now, I am printing SECOND LINE.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
?>
```

**Note**: ***If you want to check the proper output of the above code by using your local server, you have to run the complete code on CMD or XAMPP Shell.***

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try ".=" indead of "="?

```
$xml="l";
$xml.="vv";
```

will give you "lvv";

Comment: Did he say witch operating system is he using? Aanswer is completly as question ;)

Comment: However, that doesn't result in a *multi-line* string as requested in question.

Answer (score 2):

To put the strings "l" and "vv" on separate lines in the code alone:

```
$xml = "l";
$xml .= "vv"
echo $xml;
```

In this instance you're saying to append `.=` the string to the end of the previous version of that string variable. Remember that = is only an assignment operator so in your original code you're assigning the variable a new string value.

To put the strings "l" and "vv" on separate lines in the echo alone:

```
$xml = "l\nvv"
echo $xml;
```

You don't need multiple strings in this instance, as the new line character `\n` will take care of that for you.

To put the strings "l" and "vv" on separate lines in code and when echoing:

```
$xml = "l";
$xml .= "\nvv"
echo $xml;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml="l\rn";
$xml.="vv";

echo $xml;
```

But you should really look into https://www.php.net/simplexml