# What is the significance of "<<<SQL" to encapsulate a SQL query?

Tags: php, string

I'm looking at switching from *mysql* to *mysqli*, and I came across this page: http://www.codular.com/php-mysqli. I noticed that, instead of using single or double quotes, the author uses "<<<SQL" (three less than signs SQL) and "SQL" to surround his SQL query. Where can I read more about the significance and proper use of this?

Comment: thats called a HEREDOC

Comment: Note that the choice of `SQL` is arbitrary, it could be `EOF` or anything else, but `SQL` is a good choice for wrapping an SQL query.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel and Dave!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<<` starts a multiline string and is succeeded by the letters that will finish the string. In the case "SQL" on the last line finishes the string.

Look at the accepted answer of [Multi-line strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744192/php-multi-line-strings)

Forgot to say about the `;`.

Dave Morrissey responded better (oficial reference), but done it on the comment.

Thank you halfer who corrected some mistakes on the first writing.

Comment: Here's the official doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: @DaveMorrissey Thank you, I think you should add another answer, because your information is way better than mine.