# How do I echo multiple lines in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am having a hard time where this code

```
<div class = "col-md-8">
     <?php echo $row['actualpost']; ?>
</div>
```

is overlapping the column in a `div`. How can we multi line this?

Comment: what   <?php $row['actualpost']?;>  this will print ?? nothing ??

Comment: ```<?php echo  '<div class = "col-md-8">' .  $row['actualpost'] . '</div>'?>';```  should do the job.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy or paste error, but you're missing the `?` for the PHP end tag `?>`

Comment: error in typing sir sorry

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes sir, it will print.

Comment: I hope you can progress now but I will suggest you to check http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu miss type in error sir

Comment: First do not use sir word for me, just feel like you are talking with a friend . next if you are still facing problem update your question with error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm just trying to be respectful @PrafullaKumarSahu. I've got no error, the problem only is that it overlaps the div.

Comment: if  $row['actualpost'] is a string there should not be any problem with your code beside ```<? php``` space before "php" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your string using `wordwrap()` function like this:

```
wordwrap($row['actualpost'], 10, '<br>');
```

This function will wrap your long string into multiline.

**Or**

You can use this css for your `div`

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: what is 10 btw?

Comment: max length of a line, after this length your line will break

Comment: `<?php echo wordwrap($row['actualpost'], 1, '<br>'); ?>` is that how it supposed to be ?

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar yes

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar but why you are using line length only one character?

Comment: it's still the same, I've changed it to 10, it's still the same.

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar Could you please post a screenshot image?

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar try this css for your div `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj8SUzzqy6-Blj9_NbhWlXiGFfQE this is the screenshot sir

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar try that css, hope this will help. `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Thank you sir! you've saved my life

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's work

```
<div class = "col-md-8">
 <?php echo $row['actualpost']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the miss type error but that's not the answer

Comment: ohhkk...what you want ??

Comment: it overlaps in the div, i want it to be in multi line

Comment: refer this link its help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744192/multi-line-strings-in-php

Answer (score -1):

In CSS :

```
.col-md-8
{
   width:100%;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar That diesn't mean further answers can't be posted.