# Display result with input at the front/back

Tags: php

Currently i have encountered a problem is that when i displaying a result from mysql with a table , it keep showing SYNTAX error "

> syntax error, unexpected 'checkbox' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' "

When i remove the second line (checkbox) the problem solved

```
echo" <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="userID[]" value="{$row['userID']}" ></td>
    <td>{$row['username']}</td>
    <td>{$row['password']}</td>
    <td>{$row['email']}</td>
    <td>{$row['address']}</td>
 </tr>";
```

Should be have a checkbox every result that display on the php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-line strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744192/multi-line-strings-in-php)

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. What you've written is (simplified) `echo ""checkbox`if `checkbox` were a function or constant it would need to be concatenated.

Comment: your `"` quotes end the string you started on line 1 with `echo"`. https://3v4l.org/jWGmR

Comment: this `<input type="checkbox"` must be `<input type=\"checkbox\"` you must escape the quotes

Comment: my bad, sorry for the bad placement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your string is not formatted properly, you should escape the double quotes as answered by Ben. Ayoub or you can form your string properly as:

```
echo"<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='userID[]' value='" . $row['userID'] . "'></td>
    <td>{$row['username']}</td>
    <td>{$row['password']}</td>
    <td>{$row['email']}</td>
    <td>{$row['address']}</td>
 </tr>";
```