# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in E:\pemrograman\xampp\htdocs\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 4

Tags: php

php code

```
$target_path1 = $target_path1.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The first file ".basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded.";
 } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: ".basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: ".$target_path1;
 } 
 ?>
```

error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in E:\pemrograman\xampp\htdocs\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following,

```
$target_path1 = $target_path1.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The first file ".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']." has been uploaded.";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: ". $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    echo "target_path: ".$target_path1;
}
```

`$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']` gives the name of uploaded file. So `basename()` function is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the dot (`.`) to the line below:

```
echo "The first file ".basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])
." has been uploaded.";
```

Or you could use PHP's HEREDOC or NOWDOC for large strings, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848974/436721