# Use html in a php variable

Tags: php, html

I have this variable in php with html, but it doesn't work. Can you guys find any mistake...I tried and didn't find anything.
The code is:

```
$html .= '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-produtos">                
                <a href="' . $url_imagem . '" class="magnifier" rel="shadowbox">
                    <img src="' . $url_imagem . '" class="img-responsive img-produtos center-block" onerror="imgError(this);">
                </a>

            <div class="facebook-btn" onclick="window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' . $base_url . '"/facebookPublish.php?idproduto="' . $idproduto . '", "sharer", "toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325");"><i class="fa fa-facebook fc-facebook"></i>' . $lang["FACEBOOK_SHARE"] . '</div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>             
            <a href="' . $base_url . '/' . $langi . '/produtosDesc/' . $idproduto . '"><h5 class="prod-size">' . $produto . '<br>' . $refproduto . '</h5></a>                
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h5 class="text-center font-color">' . $lang['DEFAULT_PRICE'] . ' ' . $preco . ' &euro;</h5>
            <a href="' . $base_url . '/' . $langi . '/produtosDesc/' . $idproduto . '" class="btn btn-skin center-block btn-prod">' . $lang['GERAL_COMPRAR'] . '</a>';
```

Comment: It is a bad practice, Separate them, Use PHP and HTML individual.

Comment: my boss want me to make like this

Comment: Simply don't use the concatenation like `"' . $url_imagem . '"`, use like `"$url_imagem"`

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago it doesn't work how?

Comment: You didn't close first and second div.

Comment: Active erreor reporting :
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Are you sure all wariable are defined ? 
When i try with some init it's work.
`$lang = array();`
$lang['FACEBOOK_SHARE']=123;
`$lang['DEFAULT_PRICE']=123;`
`$lang['GERAL_COMPRAR']=123;`
`$preco=$refproduto=$url_imagem =$base_url = $idproduto =$produto=$langi='a';`
`$html='';`

Comment: i have those divs...i forgot to insert here

Comment: i will try to fix this Banjamin Poignant. Thanks for all guys

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to mix PHP with HTML in pretty way.

```
$html .= <<< HTML
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box-produtos">                
            <a href="{$url_imagem}" class="magnifier" rel="shadowbox">
                <img src="{$url_imagem}" class="img-responsive img-produtos center-block" onerror="imgError(this);">
            </a>

            <div class="facebook-btn" onclick="window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={$base_url}/facebookPublish.php?idproduto={$idproduto}", "sharer", "toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325");">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook fc-facebook"></i>{$lang["FACEBOOK_SHARE"]}
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>             
            <a href="{$base_url}/{$langi}/produtosDesc/{$idproduto}">
                <h5 class="prod-size">{$produto}<br/>{$refproduto}</h5>
            </a>                
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h5 class="text-center font-color">
                {$lang['DEFAULT_PRICE']} {$preco} &euro;
            </h5>
            <a href="{$base_url}/{$langi}/produtosDesc/{$idproduto}" class="btn btn-skin center-block btn-prod">
                {$lang['GERAL_COMPRAR']}
            </a>
HTML;// no indentation, must be single in line, so remove this comment
```

---

Also you were messing with facebook link in `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the mistakes of quotes you can try something like this :

```
$var="variables";
$html =<<<HTML
<h1>All your html code</h1>
<p>with all your $var or {$var}</p>
HTML;

echo $html;
```

it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php ?>` whenever specifying the php variable.

Answer (score -2):

<del>You cannot spread a string over multiple lines.</del> (Justinas sais you can. See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478495/use-html-in-a-php-variable/37478699?noredirect=1#comment62454732_37478699) below)

I think this question is related to your one:
[Best Practices: working with long, multiline strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848945/best-practices-working-with-long-multiline-strings-in-php)

**Edit 1:**

I think an other solution could also be that you have your HTML in a separate file an then read its content to your variable.

```
$html .= file_get_contents("your-file.html");
```

**Edit 2:** Removed wrong statement. As mentioned in [Justinas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478495/use-html-in-a-php-variable/37478699?noredirect=1#comment62454732_37478699).

Comment: Why do you think you can't? It's not JS. In JS you can only have single string per line and it must be concatenated. *About edit* how you will put PHP var's in this `$html` than?

Comment: Sure. You cannot simply use php variables in there. I had no need to do that in my case. I though solution may'll be helpful in case someone encounters same problem as i did.