# How to handle line breaks in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a variable having multi line text like follows. The variable value comes from db.

```
<?php   
$text = "db
value
in
multiline";
?>
```

After running some logic,  I need to append this to a div element. For that I've written like follows

```
<div id ="getme"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('getme').innerHTML = "<pre><?php print $text;?></pre>";
</script>
```

If I run the above code it throws an error in console saying

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string
```

So how do I handle pre tag in `JavaScript`/`jQuery` ?

Comment: You have a typo here `>/pre>";` missing the `<` for the closing tag.

Comment: @JayBlanchard that typo is here only. I've correct code in my end. The error is not because of the typo.

Comment: Please remove `<pre> </pre>` tags from **JS** and try again.

Comment: See the linked question's answers. In short: `document.getElementById('getme').innerHTML = "<pre>" + <?php echo json_encode($text);?> + "</pre>";` *(yes, really no quotes around the PHP part; `json_encode` will add them)*.

Comment: The unterminated string comes from your `$text = "...` lines. You're not doing multi-line text correctly in PHP. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848974/1544886 or other answers

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the json_encode idea :)