# Syntax error ';' when querying database to table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I was wondering what's my problem on this code. I was just want to query the database into tables. Thanks guys

```
<?php
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  printf(
     "<tr>";
     "<th scope='row'>" . htmlentities($row['insrt_fullname']) . "</th>";
     "<td>" . htmlentities($row['insrt_username']) . "</td>";
     "<td>" . htmlentities($row['insrt_password']) . "</td>";
     "<td>" . htmlentities($row['insrt_email']) . "</td>";
     "<td>" . htmlentities($row['insrt_designation']) . "</td>";
     "<td>";
     '<a href=/tarp_admin/connection/delete_user.php?id=' . $user_id . ' 
class=\'badge badge-danger\' onclick="myFunction">Delete</a> <a 
href=/tarp_admin/connection/delete_user.php?id=' . $user_id . ' 
class=\'badge badge-warning\'>Edit</a>';
     "</td>";   
     "</tr>";
);
?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xammp\htdocs\tarp_admin\dashboard.php on line 344

Comment: Why do you have semicolon on every string line?

Comment: oh.. should I remove the semicolon once I use the printf()?

Comment: Yeah but I am not sure if these strings on multiple lines will work.

Comment: hey thanks for noticing the ; in every string line. now I got new error though

Comment: you should just concat and store in one variable and print it. like $html= '<somehtml>';

$html += "html";

Comment: @Vanj Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849659/7351855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using semicolons on each line, that's a wrong syntax: you should put a dot instead.
Also, since you are including so much HTML in your routine, you might instead use:

```
<?php
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
?>

<tr>
<th scope='row'><?php print htmlentities($row['insrt_fullname']); ?></th>
/** ADD HERE ALL THE REST... */
</tr>

<?php
  endwhile;
?>
```

Much cleaner to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` (dot) for string concatenation instead of `;` (semicolon).