# Why Use /r/n When Developing a PHP Script?

Tags: php, coding-style

Looked everywhere on the internet for an answer to this without much luck, so here I am. I've been dissecting scripts purchased off of the CodeCanyon.net site to learn OOP and I've noticed that a lot of lines end in /r/n. Why is this common practice, and what is the practical use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they HTTP header strings?

Comment: Are you sure it's /r/n and not \r\n?

Comment: the proper line ending to use depends on what your specifically producing. outputing html? it doesnt matter. http headers? the spec requires \r\n. mime headers for emails? it depends on the specific mail transfer agent that runs on the system. a text file? \r\n for win, \n for linux, \r for really really old school mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115549/php-difference-between-r-n-and-n)

\r\n are end of line characters for Windows systems.

\n is the end of line character for UNIX systems.

It is to ensure cross-OS compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your Operating system. For Unix based system \n works fine but Windows needs the \r\n
\r is a `carriage return` and
\n a `linefeed`
in case you want to look those up

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated `\r\n` is for windows and `\n` is for unix.

To create cross OS code use [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) It is a constant that will be the current OS end of line character.