# php create txt file need cr lf

Tags: php, file, text

I have a problem with a txt file.
I create with:

```
$myFile = $data_stampa . ".txt";
$fo = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 $stringData .= $var1 . $var2 . $var3 . "\r\n";
fwrite($fo, $stringData);
fclose($fo);
```

My file are ok, but when I put on a reader, say I need "\r\n".
Where are my mistake??

EDIT 
For example, I create a line like this
1717/04/2014 2Surname                                              Name                     124/12/1969           100000216100000216PASORcgllk71xk           100000216
the white space are a fix number, for example  for surname I need 50 character. for name 30.
At the end of each line I need to put my \r\n but tho reader don't see.

Comment: Try using the constant PHP_EOL instead of \r\n

Comment: @xd6_ What makes you think that?

Comment: Can't help you without seeing how you are reading the file.  You're using `\r\n` correctly.

Comment: I tryed to use PHP_EOL but nothing, the file are the same. form me it's ok but the reader don't think so!

Comment: For reading I use an online service from Italian Police. it's easy, i put my file in a box for process.

Comment: perhaps you should try '\n': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115549/php-difference-between-r-n-and-n

Comment: I found a solution… the reader had a problem!! thanks' all.