# .serialize() method adding \r to linebreak?

Tags: php, jquery

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115554/2311074 I thought that whether `json_encode` stores a linebreak as `\n` or `\r\n` depends on the operating system. However I discovered today that I can generate both output with `json_encode` on the same operating system (Ubuntu).

Consider the example

```
  <form id='form'>
     <textarea id='amd' name='stuff'></textarea>
  </form> 
  <button id='lol'>Press Me</button>
```

with jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#lol').click(function(){
    var text = $('#amd').val();

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: ajax.php,
          data: {stuff: text}
      });
 });
```

and the following ajax.php

```
$text = $_POST['stuff'];
file_put_contents('test.txt', json_encode($text));
```

now entering the following

[image]

will write the following content in `text.txt`

> "this is a \nbreak up"

However, if I change the data attribut in the jQUery script to

```
data: $('#form').serialize()
```

then I find the following content in the `text.txt`

> "this is a \r\nbreak up"

Why is serialize() generating this additional `\r` to my linebreak \n? I am not even using windows.

Comment: Both client and server is Ubuntu?

Comment: Why idk, but if thats the case the only solution would be to do: `file_put_contents('test.txt', str_replace( '\r\n', PHP_EOL, json_encode($text)));`

Comment: @Mat yes. I use Xampp on ubuntu, so client and server are even identical. I also tried it on a real Ubuntu Server with a different Ubuntu and Win 7 Client, with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the answer is very easy. jQuery `serialize()` is adding `\r\n`, because it's developers coded it like this. You can see the code in [jquery github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a6b0705294d336ae2f63f7276de0da1195495363/src/serialize.js#L120). They replace all the occurrences of `/\r?\n/g` with `\r\n`.