# how to account for a newline in a mysql text field?

Tags: php, mysql

what's the proper syntax to account for a newline in "text" field? for example,

```
   mysql_query("select * from table where misc_note='hello\nworld'")
```

isn't working

Comment: Text fields can't display newlines so I'm not sure why you're allowing them to be entered in the first place.

Comment: can you post the `select hex(misc_note) from table where id = <the id of helloworld line>` to see if its actually \n or \r\n or maybe some spaces before or after?

Comment: Imre: 444F204E4F542063616C6C2073746576656E2120696E73746561642C2063616C6C204E6F656C6C653A202832313229207878782D78787878203A290D0A

Comment: it has `0D0A` at the end. this indicates that you should use `\r\n` instead of `\n` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want mysql way then: 
`char(10)` or `char(13),char(10)` depending if u want `\n` or `\r\n`

```
mysql_query("select * from table where misc_note=concat('hello',char(13),char(10),'world')")
```

EDIT: however it seems you may need this instead:

```
mysql_query("select * from table where misc_note like 'searchstring%'")
```

% indicates any number of any character that can occur, means you search for all notes startig with 'searhstring'.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably outputting it to text field and not in textarea. Only textarea can display new lines.

If \n is still not working you can try \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP Constant, `PHP_EOL`, which holds the End Of Line character specific to the system.

More information on this can be found at: [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Not really sure if this would help you in your certain situation, but yea, just throwing it out there.