# When do I use PHP_EOL instead of \n and vice-versa ? Ajax/Jquery client problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, line-breaks

I have a php parser that split a given string by line-breaks, doing something like this:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$content);
```

The parser works fine when working on server side. However, when I pass the content via post by ajax (using jquery's $.post method) the problem arises: line breaks are not recogniezed. So after almost an hour of tests and head-aches I decided to changed PHP_EOL by "\n" and it worked:

> $lines = explode("\n",$content);

Now it works! Damn it I lost so much time! Could somebody explain me when use PHP_EOL and "\n" properly, so I can save time in the future? Appreciate your kind answers ;)

Comment: `PHP_EOL` changes depending on the underlying filesystem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The constant [`PHP_EOL`](http://pear.php.net/reference/PHP_Compat-latest/__filesource/fsource_PHP_Compat__PHP_Compat-1.6.0a2CompatConstantPHP_EOL.php.html) should generally be used for platform-specific output.

- Mostly for *file output* really.
- Actually the file functions already transform `\n` ←→ `\r\n` on Windows systems unless used in `fopen(…, "wb")` binary mode.

For *file input* you should prefer `\n` however. While most network protocols (HTTP) are supposed to use `\r\n`, that's not guaranteed.

- Therefore it's best to break up on `\n` and remove any optional `\r` manually:

  ```
  $lines = array_map("rtrim", explode("\n", $content));
  ```

  Or use the [`file(…, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`](http://php.net/file) function right away, to leave EOL handling to PHP or [auto_detect_line_endings](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings).
- A more robust and terser alternative is using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) and a regexp:

  ```
  $lines = preg_split("/\R/", $content);
  ```

  The [`\R` placeholder](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/10/PCRE-and-newlines.html) detects any combination of <kbd>\r</kbd> + <kbd>\n</kbd>. So would be safest, and even work for Classic MacOS `≤ 9` text files (rarely seen in practice).

  <sup>Obligatory microoptimization note:

  While regex has a cost, it's surprisingly often speedier than manual loops and string postprocessing in PHP.</sup>

And there are a few classic examples where you should ***avoid*** `PHP_EOL` due to its [platform-ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373478/n-vs-php-eol-vs-br):

- Manual generation of network protocol payloads, such as HTTP over [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/fsockopen).
- For [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) and MIME construction (which really, you shouldn't do tediously yourself anyway).
- File output, ***if*** you want to *consistently* write just Unix `\n` newlines regardless of environment.

So use a literal `"\r\n"` combination when not writing to files, but preparing data for a specific context that expects *network linebreaks*.

Comment: Beware that old Macs use `\r`, this would be a better solution: `preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $str);`.

Comment: "_While regex has a cost, it's surprisingly often speedier than manual loops and string postprocessing_" - should not be all that surprising. Chances are you won't be more clever in writing the processing script than the guys who implemented, tested and optimized the regex engine.

Answer (score 10):

`PHP_EOL` should be used when writing output such as log files.

It will produce the line break specific to your platform.

Answer (score 5):

`PHP_EOL` is a constant holding the line break character(s) used by the server platform.  In the case of Windows, it's `\r\n`.  On *nix, it's `\n`.  You apparently have a Windows server.

If you were on a *nix server, that change wouldn't have fixed it, because it would be `\n`.  If you are sending data to the client (i.e. the browser), you should use `\r\n` to ensure line breaks are recognized.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP_EOL` is the line ending used by the server PHP is running on. User submitted content will probably have line ending in whatever format they use. However, instead of exploding on newlines, just using the `file()` function, it does exactly what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO using PHP_EOL is preferable

to ensure consistency between PHP and JS handling of line break, you may want to define end-of-line variable in JS using PHP_EOL

```
var eol = '<?php echo str_replace(array("\n","\r"),array('\\n','\\r'),PHP_EOL) ?>';
```

afterwards, use `eol` for splitting submitted textarea content

Comment: this is good snippet of code to show how you can "export" server-side values into JS. but the whole issue of line-breaks is much more complicated, as this thread shows [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833269/javascript-platform-independent-line-separator)

Comment: Why would the server side value of `PHP_EOL` be significant on the client side?