# substr_count not working with new lines?

Tags: php, newline, substr

This is driving me nuts, it keeps returning 0

```
substr_count('df
d
fd
f
df', '\n');
```

if I use a letter like "d", it works fine

```
substr_count('df
d
fd
f
df', 'd');
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for control characters:

```
var_dump(substr_count('df
d
fd
f
df', "\n"));
```

Answer (score 4):

'\n' is not the same as "\n". '\n' is text comprising a slash and the letter "n", whereas "\n" is a newline character.

Suggest you read the [relevant section](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) of the PHP manual about strings, particularly where it talks about single and double quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alix and Mark: please use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`. Newlines differ on the different platforms (Windows/Linux/Mac), but `PHP_EOL` is always right. See this question for more info on the subject: [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Comment: Humm... I would argue that `\n` is safer in general because it's present in both `\n` and `\r\n`, the exception would be `\r` (old Mac). If the input string comes from a *nix system (`\n`) and the server runs on Windows (`\r\n`), `PHP_EOL` will not work. To be on the safe side, I always normalize newlines to `\n` with the following regex: `$str = preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $str);`.

Comment: @AlixAxel Hmm, seems true for input, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4975441/251760 Didn't knew that, thanks for your comment!