# Make html in view source appear on each line

Tags: php, html

How do I make the html in view source of a browser appear on each line? I'm using php to generate my web pages using a template like this:

```
$template  = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
$template .= '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">';
$template .= '<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
echo $template;
```

Problem is, it all appears on one line when I view it using view source in a browser.

How do I make it appear on different lines?

I tried using \r\n in the template, but it wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$template  = <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"; content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
EOT;

echo $template;
```

Using heredoc

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2):

You should use `PHP_EOL` like this:

```
$template  = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . PHP_EOL;
$template .= '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">' . PHP_EOL;
$template .= '<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' . PHP_EOL;
echo $template;
```

Comment: this won't work in windows. should use . "\r\n" instead of PHP_EOL which is only \n

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975411/when-do-i-use-php-eol-instead-of-n-and-vice-versa-ajax-jquery-client-problem