# How to print each $x on a new line?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$x="101.5degrees"; 
(double)$x;
print_r($x . '\n'); 
(int)$x; 
echo (string)$x; 
?>
```

I expect to print the value of x on a new line.

Comment: The codes are incorrect. Initially `$x`  is not an array, thus you should not be using `print_r()`. You want to list the `$x` values after you cast it as `double`, `int` and `string`, right?

Comment: totally agree with @Raptor

Comment: Yes @Raptor totally agree with you. But even if I change the line print_r($x. '"\n") to `echo $x; echo "\n"` still it is not working.

Comment: If I were you, I won't hardcode \n, as line breaks are OS-dependent. Some use \r, some use \r\n. That's why `PHP_EOL` comes to play.

Comment: @Raptor just for the sake of understanding as I am using an linux system then \n should work in my case know? Why any escape characters are not working like '\r', '\r\n'?

Comment: If you don't specify Content Type as `text/plain`, it's displayed as HTML. In HTML, \n  has no visual effects at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers didn't really solve OP's problem, here is the correct way of using line breaks in PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$x = "101.5degrees"; 
echo (double)$x . PHP_EOL;
echo (int)$x . PHP_EOL; 
echo (string)$x . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
101.5
101
101.5degrees
```

Comment: Thanks @Raptor for the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x="101.5degrees"; 
(double)$x;
print_r($x); 
(int)$x; 
echo PHP_EOL.(string)$x;
```

try this out
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373478/n-vs-php-eol-vs-br)