# How I can take textarea lines to array in php after POST data?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I type textarea text, for example:

> 22.333.45.16
>
> 122.12.65.143
>
> 14.14.111.11234
>
> text

How I can take every line to array? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: "possible or not" the former

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$input = $_POST["nameOfTextarea"];
$lines = explode("\n", $input);
```

This splits the string into an array based on the delimiter `\n` (which is a line break). [Here's the docs for explode().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is recommended over `\n`

Comment: You got me again; fixed that too ;)

Comment: @Dagon Got to disagree with your second point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975411/when-do-i-use-php-eol-instead-of-n-and-vice-versa-ajax-jquery-client-problem

Comment: Ha! Take that! Rolled back per @Steve's comment B)

Comment: funny i was going to post that to support my case - i have never been clear on this. anything in that post that covers this particular case?