# Newline not working in php

Tags: php, file, text, newline, file-handling

This is the code.I don't know where I have made a mistake.I tried with single quote as well.
 I tried it but all items come in one line.

```
 $output_line=$item."\n";
 fwrite($myfile,$output_line);
```

Comment: for a txt file that's valid, if its a browser it would expect HTML. you may need "\r\n" depending on OS

Comment: What about using PHP_EOL instead of "\n" as a test? That way it should be whatever return the system itself uses?

Comment: How many items are there? What is $item? Is it one item in string or several in array?

Comment: Andreas , There are 7 items array

Comment: @Tayyab is $item an array? Are you sure? You have said in comments below that answers where $item is string is correct. If $item is an array those answers should not work

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`.

```
 $output_line=$item . PHP_EOL ;
```

Comment: OP says $item is an array, this should create a array to string conversion error

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which produces `\r\n` or `\n`

```
$data = 'some data' . PHP_EOL . 'this should be on new line';
$fp = fopen('my_file', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

// File output

```
some data
this should be on new line
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975411/when-do-i-use-php-eol-instead-of-n-and-vice-versa-ajax-jquery-client-problem

Comment: hmm that is the answer i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Line break representation can be different on different operating system. In PHP there is an predefined constant called PHP_EOL which return the correct 'End Of Line' symbol for current platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2.

Therefore, your code should be as below:

```
$output_line=$item.PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile,$output_line);
```

Comment: OP says $item is an array, this should create a array to string conversion error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use implode to add a "text" between each item.
Implode takes an array and adds a string in between each item and makes it all string.

```
$output_line=implode(" PHP_EOL", $item);
fwrite($myfile,$output_line);
```

This will now make:

```
Item1 PHP_EOL
Item2 PHP_EOL
Item3 PHP_EOL
```