# PHP - Read text file and output contents as links won't work

Tags: php

I have a text file in the same folder as the script I'm trying to run. It has several URL links each on a new line like so:

```
hxxp://www.example.com/example1/a.doc
hxxp://www.example.com/example2/b.xls
hxxp://www.example.com/example3/c.ppt
```

I'm trying to link these files but it only lists the last file in the list.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $getLinks = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/links.txt');
    $files = explode("\n", $getLinks);

    foreach ($files as $file) {

        if (substr($file, 0, 23) == 'hxxp://www.example.com/') {
            $ext = pathinfo(strtolower($file));
            $linkFile = basename(rawurldecode($file));

            if ($ext['extension'] == 'doc') {
                echo '<a href="' . $file . '"><img src="images/word.png" />&nbsp;' . $linkFile . '</a><br />';
            } elseif ($ext['extension'] == 'xls') {
                echo '<a href="' . $file . '"><img src="images/excel.png" />&nbsp;' . $linkFile . '</a><br />';
            } elseif ($ext['extension'] == 'ppt') {
                echo '<a href="' . $file . '"><img src="images/powerpoint.png" />&nbsp;' . $linkFile . '</a><br />';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

*note: I've tried using the file function as well with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getLinks = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/links.txt');
$files = explode("\r\n", $getLinks);
```

I'm assuming you're on windows, the same as me.

`\n` isn't the whole windows new line character Use `\r\n`

When I replaced \n with \r\n it worked as expected

Comment: Use PHP_EOL instead of "\r\n" that way your code is portable between nix, windows, mac. $files = explode(PHP_EOL, $getLinks);
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol

Comment: @mlaw: That's not exactly correct. In this case I believe the problem is that the OP is processing a Windows-style EOL file with PHP running  on nix. PHP_EOL won't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this code in many ways:

1. Use `file` instead of `file_get_contents` to have the lines put into an array automatically
2. Use `strpos` instead of `substr` -- more efficient
3. Use `strrpos` to get the file extension -- faster and foolproof, as know exactly how it behaves
4. You should be using `rawurlencode` instead of `rawurldecode` because you are *creating* urls, not reading them
5. The `if` conditionals for the extensions should be replaced by an array lookup

Making all these changes, we have:

```
$lines = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/links.txt');

$extensions = array(
    'doc' => 'word.png',
    'xls' => 'excel.png',
    'ppt' => 'powerpoint.png',
);

foreach ($lines as $file) {
    if (strpos($file, 'hxxp://www.example.com/') !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $ext = strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1));

    if (empty($extensions[$ext])) {
        continue;
    }

    printf('<a href="%s"><img src="images/%s" />&nbsp;%s</a><br />',
           $file, $extensions[$ext], rawurlencode(basename($file)));
}
```