# SMTP: \r\n\r (without second \n) as double newline

Tags: smtp, newline, rfc

I have SMTP parser that works mostly fine. There is a problem when receiving traffic from third party software that sends double newlines as "\r\n\r" (without the second "\n"). Currently such connections are terminated as non-compliant SMTP. Can somebody explain what exactly RFC says about such "funny" double newlines? Can I asume that software that sends data like that is doing something really wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC2821. Section 2.3.7:

> SMTP commands and, unless altered
>   by a service extension, message
>   data, are transmitted in "lines". 
>   Lines consist of zero or more data
>   characters terminated by the sequence
>   ASCII character "CR" (hex value    0D)
>   followed immediately by ASCII
>   character "LF" (hex value 0A).

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

--Dave

Comment: RFC later says: "SMTP client implementations MUST NOT transmit these characters except when they are intended as line terminators and then MUST, as indicated above, transmit them only as a <CRLF> sequence." Since RFC explicitly requires <CRLF> I think it's safe to assume that understanding app that sends data with <CRLFCR> is not needed. I still do not see the reason for application to send newlines in funny ways.

Answer (score -2):

Various operating systems have various representations for Newline characters. Check the [instructions here on newline characters.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). By the way its a common practice among programmers to use both the `\n` and `\r` together to prevent any conflicts on the system. You need to check which newline character is supported by your system. If its `\r` then you are getting both the required characters. But if its `\n`, then the error lies with the sender.

Comment: I did read the wikipedia before asking, that's why I'm asking. I can see the reason to accept \n\n and \r\r and \r\n\r\n as double newline but \r\n\r looks just weird. First you use Windows newline and just after it you use MacOS9 newline. The problem with "\r\n\r" is that you do not know how many newlines are there. Three? Two? one and a half?