# Breakline in ssis message does not work

Tags: string, ssis, ssis-2012, linefeed, script-task

I am creating a message inside a string using a Script task

The code would look like this:

```
Message = Description +"\n" + Message;
```

The idea is to receive a message like this:

```
Description
Description
```

and so on

Within a messagebox I can see this result, but when I open the mail, the message is composed of one single line:

```
Description1  Description2
```

I have also changed "\n" for "\n\r", Environment.NewLine. But it didn't work.

Could you explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Send how? Which class did you use, what settings? Did you use HTML formatting? Newline characters are ignored in HTML and treated as whitespace

Comment: In ssis I am creating the message dynamically. At the end of the ETL I am adding the variable to the body of the mail using the Send Mail Task

Comment: The SMTP standard uses CRLF, ie `\r\n`, for newline. WIndows also uses `\r\n`. AFAIK no OS uses `\n\r`. The duplicate question also explains that SMTP sends messages in lines, so your message is transmitted as a single line by all mail servers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP: \r\n\r (without second \n) as double newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167050/smtp-r-n-r-without-second-n-as-double-newline)

Comment: I believe the SSIS "Send Mail Task" attempts to send HTML-ified email so replace those `\n` with `<br/>` and see what happens

Answer (score 4):

You need to typecast it as below:

(DT_STR,2,1252)"\r\n"

For example...the below expression in Execute SQL task is dynamic SQL

```
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[OBJ_COUNT]([OBJ_NAME], [OBJ_COUNT]) VALUES ( " + "'EMPLOYEE_MASTER', " + (DT_STR, 10, 1252) (@[User::EMP_MAST_COUNT])+" );" + (DT_STR,2,1252)"\r\n" + "GO " + (DT_STR,2,1252)"\r\n" + "INSERT INTO [dbo].[OBJ_COUNT]([OBJ_NAME], [OBJ_COUNT]) VALUES ( " + "'DEPT_MASTER', " + (DT_STR, 10, 1252) (@[User::DEPT_MAST_COUNT])+" );" + (DT_STR,2,1252)"\r\n"+ "GO "
```

And will give output as below...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OBJ_COUNT]([OBJ_NAME], [OBJ_COUNT]) VALUES ( 'EMPLOYEE_MASTER', 2514);
GO 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OBJ_COUNT]([OBJ_NAME], [OBJ_COUNT]) VALUES ( 'DEPT_MASTER', 2541);
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Try "\n\n" . This works but adds an extra line break. In most cases it is adequate.