# Using end of line in PHP echo string

Tags: php

I am trying to write a PHP script that `echo`s a string, but it doesn't recognize the end of line function in there.

For example,

```
echo "thank you \n "
echo "for coming over"
```

The `\n` is ignored and it prints the whole line as `thank you for coming over`.

I got the same result for the following to:

```
echo "thank you " . PHP_EOL.;
echo "for coming over" . PHP_EOL.;
```

Comment: Try inserting `<br>`.

Comment: Look at your source code, you'll see that the new line has been inserted. It's just that the browser ignores new lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Comment: Are you outputting to a browser, or to a command line (or somewhere else)?  Because browsers ignore whitespace, including newlines, except in certain tags or when certain styles are present.  You need to clarify your question.  Most of the answers below assume you are outputting to browser.

Comment: Why the dot after `PHP_EOL`?

Answer (score 27):

There are different ways to solve that:

### Using Pre-formatted text

```
echo '<pre>'; // pre-formatted text, \n should work
echo "thank you \n ";
echo "for coming over";
echo '</pre>';
```

### Changing the content type

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo "thank you \n ";
echo "for coming over";
```

You browser will now properly read the output as text.

### Using the HTML break element

```
echo "thank you <br>\n ";
echo "for coming over";
```

So output always depends on what you want to output. Is it text? Is it HTML? Is it some text within HTML? Depending on what you need you should take care on the format and formatting.

Comment: I just fixed your code (missing ; and </pre>), hope it's okay.

Comment: Related to *Using Pre-formatted text*, [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) css property can be used too.

Answer (score 18):

If you are doing this in a browser, replace `\n` with `<br />`. The file line breaks are not rendered in an HTML page, unless specified via CSS or if they're enclosed in certain tags. You could also optionally change the file type to `text/plain`, but I don't think that would be desired.

Comment: `nl2br()` function does that automatically for you.

Answer (score 10):

try this
normally you can use

```
 echo "thank you <br>";
 echo "for coming over<br>";
```

and at time of file handling

```
echo "thank you ".PHP_EOL."";
echo "for coming over".PHP_EOL."";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print text containing eol's in html, give [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) a shot

```
$str = "thank you \n ";
$str .= "for coming over";
nl2br($str);
```

It will add HTML line breaks before all eols.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source of the web page from browser, there will be a new line. Since in HTML, whitespaces like newline, tabs or spaces are ignored, you can't see them in the browser. You need to use `<br />` or `&nbsp;` etc. to print what you want.