# Add a linebreaks in Whatsapp url message using sprintf

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, whatsapp, orders

I wanted to do a line break in the Whatsapp URL message while the message is generated in sprintf and then goes through the urlencode.

code below

```
$msg = sprintf( __("Hello %s %s, your order #%s has been received. The order amount is %s %s. Your payment method is %s. Please Confirm your order by replying *Confirm*. Please contact us if you have any question regarding your order. You can view your order here ".$orderlink." Thank you.", "woocommerce"),
            $order->get_billing_first_name(),
            $order->get_billing_last_name(),
            $order->get_order_number(),
            $order->get_currency(),
            $order->get_total(),
            $order->get_payment_method_title(),
        );

        $whatsappnum = WC()->countries->get_country_calling_code( $order->get_billing_country() ) . $order->get_billing_phone();
        update_post_meta( $_GET['order_id'], '_wapp_sent_processing', 'true' ); // Mark order as WhatsApp message sent
        wp_redirect( 'https://wa.me/' . $whatsappnum . '?text=' . urlencode($msg) ); // Redirect WhatsApp
```

this message is generated for woocommerce orders and a action button is sending it to buyers whatsapp.

currently, the message is displayed in WhatsApp without any linebreak

please check image
[image]

I want this message to have linebreaks to look more clean and easy to read.

Thanks

**Update**

I did some debugging and found out that it's happening because of wp_redirect, if you look at the wp_redirect code you'll find out that it's removing the new line %0A from the URL.

I have tried this code by setting the strip_new_lines to false but it's still not working.

```
        $number = 9;
        $str = "Beijing";
        $msg2 = sprintf("Hello %s %s, \n your order # has been received. The order amount is . Your payment method is. Please Confirm your order by replying *Confirm*. Please contact us if you have any question regarding your order. You can view your order here Thank you",$number,$str);

        $whatsappnum = WC()->countries->get_country_calling_code( $order->get_billing_country() ) . $order->get_billing_phone();
        update_post_meta( $_GET['order_id'], '_wapp_sent_processing', 'true' ); // Mark order as WhatsApp message sent
      
        $strip_new_lines = false;
        $location = "https://wa.me/".$whatsappnum."?text=".urlencode($msg);
        $status = 302;
        wp_redirect( $location, $status, $strip_new_lines ); // Redirect WhatsApp

        exit;
```

it's working fine with the PHP header but I want to use the wp_redirect

```
header('Location: https://wa.me/+921111111111?text='.$encodmsg);
```

Comment: How is this code failing? Where is the problem statement and the desired result?  This sounds like a task that you are putting to Stack Overflows volunteers so that they do your work for free.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. There were many typo issues the question was not clear.
I edited it and hopefully explained it well now.

Comment: You can try `\r\n`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i have tried it already but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with woocommerce but maybe this post helps: [Using end of line in PHP echo string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519976/using-end-of-line-in-php-echo-string)

There could be some things to try like the `<pre>` element or nl2br() function or `<br>` element?

Comment: I have tried it all nothing of these is helping.
the message is in sprintf and then goes through urlencode that's why it's more challanging

Comment: Then the problem lies in your encoding? Check the source code of the whatsapp page to see whats rendered there?

Comment: the WhatsApp link should render %0A for linebreak, \n is adding %2C in url after encode