# How can I find out how many times a foreach construct loops in PHP, without using a "counter" variable?

Tags: php

If I have a `foreach` construct, like this one:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br />";
}
```

I know I can keep track of how many times the construct loops by using a counter variable, like this:

```
$counter = 0;

$foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item.' is item #'.$counter. "<br />";
    $counter++;
}
```

But is it possible to do the above *without* using a "counter" variable?
That is, is it possible to know the iteration count within the `foreach` loop, *without* needing a "counter" variable?

Note: I'm totally okay with using counters in my loops, but I'm just curious to see if there is a provision for this built directly into PHP... It's like the awesome `foreach` construct that simplified certain operations which are clunkier when doing the same thing using a `for` construct.

Comment: what's wrong with using a counter?

Comment: You could use sizeof($items)...

Comment: does php have $items.IndexOf($item)?

Comment: You could use `count($items)`

Comment: What are you trying to do that a counter does not solve?

Comment: Sorry guys for not being very clear the first time; I have updated the question in hopes of making it more clear. :)

Comment: if it's about outputting html, you could give `<ol><li></li></ol>` a try to get a automatically numbered list. just a thought..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible unless your `$items` is an array having **contiguous** indexes (keys) starting with the 0 key.

If it have **contiguous** indexes do:

```
foreach ($items as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k, ' = ', $v, '<br />', PHP_EOL;
}
```

But as others have stated, there is nothing wrong using a counter variable.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on PHP_EOL a bit? I looked it up on PHP.net but it didn't really elaborate on the constant.

Comment: @Titus Check out my answer in [When do I use the PHP constant “PHP_EOL”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol/6666554#6666554).

Answer (score 5):

There's no easier way - that's kinda what count variables are for.

I'm assuming that you want to know the current count *during* the loop.  If you just need to know it after, use `count($items)` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell how many time it WILL loop or SHOULD have looped by doing a

```
$loops = count($items);
```

However that will only work if your code does not skip an iteration in any way.

Answer (score 1):

foreach loops N times, where N is just the size of the array. So you can use `count($items)` to know it.

*EDIT*
Of course, as noticed by Bulk, your loop should not break (or maybe continue, but I would count a `continue` as a loop, though shorter...)