# Does PHP Have a "built-in" iterator in a Foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, iterator, phpexcel

I'm using a foreach loop to go through the REQUEST array, as I want to have an easy way to utilize the REQUEST array's keys and values.

However, I also want to have a numerical index of how many times the loop has run, as I'm writing a spreadsheet with PHPExcel, and I want to use the `SetCellValue` function. I'm thinking something like this:

```
foreach( $_REQUEST as $key => $value){
    $prettyKeys = ucwords(preg_replace($patt_underscore," ",preg_replace($patt_CC,"_",$key)));
    $prettyVals = ucwords(preg_replace($patt_underscore," ",preg_replace($patt_CC,"_",$value)));
    // Replace CamelCase with Underscores, then replace the underscores with spaces and then capitalize string
    // "example_badUsageOfWhatever" ==> "Example Bad Usage Of Whatever"


    $myExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue( "A". $built-in-foreach-loop-numerical-index ,$prettyKeys);
    $myExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue( "B". $built-in-foreach-loop-numerical-index ,$prettyVals);
}
```

I know I can easily implement something like `$c = 0` outsite the foreach and then just increment it each time the loop is run, but is there something cleaner?

Comment: In a word, no. As in pretty much any language, if you want a counter you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Use `for` loop if you need this functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP's foreach does not have this functionality built in ([per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)).  Use a [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to have an iterator or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The `for` loop will give you an automatic counter, but no way to cycle through your `$_REQUEST` associative array.  The `foreach` loop will let you cycle through, but without a built-in counter.  It's a tradeoff, but at least it's a very manageable one (only takes 2 lines of code to build the counter)!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in iterator numerical index.  You can solve this problem in other ways, though.

The most obvious way to do this is using a simple `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0, $numFoo = count($foo); $i < $numFoo; ++$i) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also use `foreach` with a counter variable:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($foo as $key => $value) {
    // ...
    ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SPL Iterator Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).  I'm sure there is something in there you can utilize for this.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources for learning how to use these? I've never seen that facet of PHP.

Comment: I never found any, I've used IteratorIterator, LimitIterator and just had to figure it out myself.  Go Google crazy, I'm sure it's out there

Answer (score 1):

### Using a For-Loop

You definitely can do this with a for-loop, it's just a bit ugly:

```
reset($array);
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    // $i is your counter
    // Extract current key and value
    list($key, $value) = array(key($array), current($array));

    // ...body of the loop...

    // Move to the next array element
    next($array);
}
```

---

### Extend ArrayIterator

My preferred way would be to extend [ArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php). Add an internal counter, then override next() and rewind() to update the counter. The counter gives the 0-based key of the current array element:

```
class MyArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
    private $numericKey = 0;

    public function getNumericKey()
    {
        return $this->numericKey;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->numericKey++;
        parent::next();
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->numericKey = 0;
        parent::rewind();
    }
}

// Example:
$it = new MyArrayIterator(array(
    'string key' =>'string value',
    1 =>'Numeric key value',
));
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($it as $key =>$value) {
    print_r(array(
        'numericKey' =>$it->getNumericKey(),
        'key' =>$key,
        'value' =>$value,
    ));
}

// Output:
// Array
// (
//     [numericKey] => 0
//     [key] => string key
//     [value] => string value
// )
// Array
// (
//     [numericKey] => 1
//     [key] => 1
//     [value] => Numeric key value
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered also here: [How can I find out how many times a foreach construct loops in PHP, without using a "counter" variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699043/how-can-i-find-out-how-many-times-a-foreach-construct-loops-in-php-without-usin)

Shortly, no. There isn't any easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of each key of $_REQUEST array:

`$req_index= array_flip (array_keys($_REQUEST));`

Now you have the numerical index of the current element through `$req_index[$key]`, which gives also the  number of iterations of the loop:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
    $prettyKeys = ucwords(preg_replace($patt_underscore," ",preg_replace($patt_CC,"_",$key)));
    $prettyVals = ucwords(preg_replace($patt_underscore," ",preg_replace($patt_CC,"_",$value)));
    // Replace CamelCase with Underscores, then replace the underscores with spaces and then capitalize string
    // "example_badUsageOfWhatever" ==> "Example Bad Usage Of Whatever"

    //THE NUMERICAL INDEX IS $req_index[$key]
    $myExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue( "A". $req_index[$key], $prettyKeys);
    $myExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue( "B". $req_index[$key], $prettyVals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `foreach` with combination of `array_values()` which will give you keys for each element in the array.

For Example:

```
$colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];

foreach(array_values($colors) as $key => $color) {
    echo "$color $key";
}
/**Output:
red 0
blue 1
green 2*/
```