# PHP: fgets equivalent for reading from the _bottom_ of a file?

Tags: php, file, file-io

I have a file that updates itself by appending,  however this file becomes huge (500MB). I would like to read the last 50 lines in the file. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tail -n50 will return the last 50 lines of the file.

```
$filename = 'test.html';
$output = shell_exec('exec tail -n50 ' . $filename);
echo $output;
```

Therefore, you don't have to load the entire file in memory.

Edit:

If you want to echo "`<br>`" after each line you do:

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $output);
```

Comment: However, be careful that $filename isn't something malicious.

Comment: Yes if the purpose of reading the file is not for internal use. In that case, you can always remove bad characters (using regexp), check if the file exists (file_exists) and check if it's readable (is_readable) before you load check the last 50 lines. I strongly recommend security if this your case.

Comment: that looks like a really nice solution, one question though, how can I get a `<br>` after each line?

Comment: I updated my code. Read about PHP_EOL @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `fseek` to move the file pointer a certain number of bytes from the end of the file:

```
$fp = fopen('myfile','r');
fseek($fp,-1024, SEEK_END);
$last_kb_of_file = fgets($fp,1024);
```

You'll have to tell `fgets` how many **bytes** you want to read, not how many lines. It has no idea what the format of the file is. You'll have to split the result on a newline and see if you have 50 lines.