# Need help in strtok function when the first token is null

Tags: c, strtok, stringtokenizer, proc

Need help in strtok function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100], *ptr = NULL;

    memset(string, 0, 100);
    strcpy(string, "abc#efg#xyz");

    ptr = strtok(string, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);

    ptr = strtok(NULL, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);

    ptr = strtok(NULL, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ptr = [abc]
ptr = [efg]
ptr = [xyz]
```

This is fine, but when if the first token is null then the first call to strtok returns the second token.  My understanding is that it will return a null in the first call as the token is not present.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100], *ptr = NULL;

    memset(string, 0, 100);
    strcpy(string, "#efg#xyz");

    ptr = strtok(string, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);

    ptr = strtok(NULL, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);

    ptr = strtok(NULL, "#");
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = [%s]\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}***
```

The output is

```
ptr = [efg]
ptr = [xyz]
ptr = [(null)]
```

Comment: Read: [`strtok()` source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/string.subproj/strtok.c)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

> To determine the beginning and the end of a token, the function first
>   scans from the starting location for **the first character not contained
>   in delimiters**

So I think that this is the correct behavior you are seeing. `strtok()` starts from your first character, see's it as a delimeter, ignores it, and seeks forward for the first non-delimiter character.

I guess the way around it is to check that the first character is not a delimiter yourself.

Checked C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E)) too and the definition is the same:

> The first call in the sequence searches the string pointed to by `s1`
>   for the first character that is not contained in the current separator
>   string pointed to by `s2`

In fact, the standard gives an example in 7.21.5.8, bullet point 8:

```
#include <string.h>
static char str[] = "?a???b,,,#c";
char *t;
t = strtok(str, "?"); // t points to the token "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `strtok` manual page (from `man strtok`):

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter characters in the
>   parsed string is considered to be a single  delimiter.  Delimiter
>   characters at the start or end of the string are ignored.  Put another
>   way: the tokens returned by strtok() are always nonempty strings.

Comment: I was to quote the same sntence at the same moment. Congratulations, you won :-)