# End of line character for PHP-generated ASCII txt download

Tags: php, html, download, http-headers, ascii

I want to do an ASCII text download of user-selected SQL data, that can be opened immediately in notepad.  DB connection works fine, as do "header" commands to initiate download, but I'll be damned if I can get the end-of-line characters to show up properly.

The header is statically defined via:

```
$header = <<<EOD
  #Some header information
  #goes here on multiple
  #lines
  EOD;
```

with each row data being concatenated with tabs:

```
$RS_SQL = $DBinterface->dbGetRecordSet($someQuery);
foreach($RS_SQL as $row) {
  $rowdata = '';
  foreach($row as $key=>$val) {
    if((!(int)$key) && $key!='0') {
      $rowdata[] = $row[$key];
    }
  }
  $dataOutput.=implode("\t",$rowdata)."\n";
}
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SQLDataExport.txt");
echo $header."\n".$dataOutput;
```

Header shows up in notepad fine, and all the tab spacing is exactly as designed... However, any attempt to format rows nicely via \r or \n characters result in a single line with unknown characters (square boxes) where the linefeeds should be.

I've tried writing the file to the server, then reading the stream and outputting; tried variations on the header information... Kinda get the idea that there's something odd with the way the page is being downloaded to the browser via binary, but?

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not related to your square box issue, but notepad will need `\r\n` instead of just `\n` else it will ignore the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "\n" or "\r\n", use [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for this.  It handles any cross platform issues and is good for writing files that are meant to be saved on the server or client.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) has some information and could be considered related to what you are trying to do.

You would use it like so:

```
$RS_SQL = $DBinterface->dbGetRecordSet($someQuery);
foreach($RS_SQL as $row) {
  $rowdata = '';
  foreach($row as $key=>$val) {
    if((!(int)$key) && $key!='0') {
      $rowdata[] = $row[$key];
    }
  }
  $dataOutput.=implode("\t",$rowdata).PHP_EOL;
}
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SQLDataExport.txt");
echo $header."\n".$dataOutput;
```

Comment: Thank you - that works nicely.  I will trade all my end-lines to that constant.

Interestingly, though, this is not a cross-platform issue... IIS on Windows Server talking to windows notepad via IE.

Comment: Very good. Feel free to accept the answer so that others know that this worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in the `header` as UTF-8:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Hope it helps! :) If not, check your PHP code for any UTF-8 `BOM`!