# why chr() function at the end of echo

Tags: php

I've found this line in one of the codes coppied from web but have no ide why they use char() function at the end of it. Please let me know why it is used, what it does and what if I don't use it all.

Thanks in advance.

**CODE:**

```
$crlf = chr(13) . chr(10);

echo '<html><head><title>Whatever</title></head><body>Hello</body></html>' . $crlf;
```

Comment: It's instead of writing `"\r\n"`.

Comment: to echo a line break.

Comment: They are not using char at the end of it, they are using whatever the function returns, in this case it would be: the CarriageReturn (\r) and LineFeed(\n) in this case (a new line)

Comment: The variable name says it all :-)

Comment: @TerrySeidler `PHP_EOL` is platform related, so if you had a website on windows and then ported it to linux you could encounter some problems later on.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` *should* be platform-independent as far as I know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol

Comment: Thanks guys I learned it now.

Comment: @TerrySeidler What I mean is the following, if you wrote `PHP_EOL` to a file, and later on you used `explode("\r\n", $data);` on windows it would work fine, but if you then go on linux, `PHP_EOL` will not use `\r\n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chr(13)` is equivalent to `"\r"` and `chr(10)` is equivalent to `"\n"`.

So, `$crlf = chr(13) . chr(10);` is a string containing `"\r\n"`, a [CRLF (newline)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) as the variable name states.

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks, I'm a little lysdexic sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

`chr(13)` and `chr(10)` return the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) representations of "Carriage return" and "Line feed". These characters can also be written as "\r\n" in PHP. **On a Windows system, CR+LF together represent a newline.** (See [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n))

Answer (score 0):

The "chr()" function returns a specific ASCII value. See [php chr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) and [ascii chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) - Which should help you understand more :)

Answer (score 0):

The questioner asked

> Please let me know why it is used, what it does and what if I don't use it all.

And I don't think anybody answered that yet ...

The programmer is presumably trying to format the HTML code of the page so that is is more readable when displayed through a browser's 'view source' functionality. So the $crlf could be omitted safely, so long as you don't care what the HTML source looks like.

Seems an odd decision to use two function calls rather than typing "\r\n", but who knows, the coder may have had his/her reasons.