# Can't replace echo with file_put_contents on getAttribute

Tags: php

i'm trying to run `file_put_contents` instead of `echo` but I can not solve it.
This is my code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$a = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($a as $link){
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br />';
```

I tried to update `echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br />'`; with `file_put_contents("$project.txt", $link->getAttribute('href').'<br />');` but instead of getting something like this:

```
http://domain1.com/url-page-1/
http://domain2.com/url-page-2/
http://domain3.com/url-page-3
(...)
```

I got just this:

```
http://domain1.com/url-page-1/<br />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`, FILE_APPEND`](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: The basic reason for that your code it's not working is because you rewrite your file `$project.txt` with every loop. As @Amal Murali well said the you should give the third parameter to `file_put_contents`, `FILE_APPEND`, for the file to not be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PHP_EOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128564/1438393) instead:

```
file_put_contents("$project.txt", $link->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL);
```

If you want to append to the file, then use the [`FILE_APPEND`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) flag:

```
$text = $link->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("$project.txt", $text , FILE_APPEND);
```

Your `foreach` loop would look like this:

```
foreach($a as $link){
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br />';
    $text = $link->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents("$project.txt", $text , FILE_APPEND);
}
```