# New line in PHP

Tags: php, csv, line

I am making CSV file and I need to make a new line after each procedure. The standard \n\r doesn't work.

The code looks like:

```
while ($resultD=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryDown)) 
        {
            $csv.= $resultD["first_name"].' , '.$resultD["last_name"].' , '.$resultD["login"].' , '.$resultD["password"].'\n\r';
        }
        $filename= "export.csv";
        $theFile=fopen($filename,"w");
        fwrite($theFile, $csv);
```

Comment: ['\n\r' or "\r\n" there's some difference :)](https://eval.in/194725)

Comment: Perhaps [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv) and related functions would benefit you instead of trying to work with CSV more manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use :

```
$csv .= '...' . "\r\n";
```

Or

```
$csv .= '...' . PHP_EOL;
```

Or give a look at `fputcsv` to get it work easily : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 6):

Use `"\r\n"`, instead of `'\n\r'`.

You need the double quotes `""` to recognize the escape sequences `\r` and `\n`. Single quotes won't do it.

*EDIT*

As Michael mentioned, you can also use `PHP_EOL`, again instead of `'\n\r'`.

This generates a newline character that is compatible across multiple platforms.

---

From PHP documentation on [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **Note**: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: There is `PHP_EOL` to do it in a platform-independent way, see stackoverflow question [When do I use the PHP constant “PHP_EOL”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol).

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv.= $resultD["first_name"].' , '.$resultD["last_name"].' , '.$resultD["login"].' , '.$resultD["password"]."\n";
```

Comment: Inclusion of an explanation is much more helpful than a code-only answer.

Comment: Examples are helpful, but to exemplify what you are explaining. With just a code snippet, it's not immediately obvious what is different or _why_ it works.