# How to pass CRLF as an argument to command line program?

Tags: php, linux, windows, cmd

I need to pass an actual CRLF to a program as an argument.

If I do:

```
shell_exec('echo "Hello World" >t.txt');
```

it works fine. But when I do:

```
shell_exec('echo "Hello 
World" >t.txt');
```

it breaks. I need a way to pass an actual CRLF as an argument because `ffmpeg` requires it when using -headers.

I need a solution for Windows/Linux.

Comment: have you tried a simple Batch script?

Comment: Try `"\r\n"`.  Depending on your platform your existing 2 line code may only be a newline.

Comment: aside from that maybe regular VBS also what is the difference between the first one and the other one?

Comment: @CS_STEM The other one has a CRLF after "Hello and when it runs it just shows "Hello and saves nothing to t.txt. VBS and Batch will not work in Linux.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It's ignoring '\r\n' and "\r\n" is the same as in my example.

Comment: as far as batch goes after or before the shell_exec try doing the `echo "Hello World" > t.txt` this will save the string to a txt doc named t.txt now if this is a program you can change the directory with `CD "C:\users..." ` for example. and I figured linux had to be different. hope this bit helps

Comment: @CS_STEM The problem is that a program needs CRLF as a parameter, like this: myprog.exe -one -two -threeCRFL -four -five

Comment: @Tom Read accepted answer to [cmd.exe quoted string expansion?](http://superuser.com/questions/475958/cmd-exe-quoted-string-expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`PHP_EOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853511/17300) instead of the escaped newline and/or carriage return.

```
<?php
shell_exec('echo "Hello' . PHP_EOL . 'World" >t.txt');
?>
```

This worked for me on Linux and OS X — I don't have a Win system to try it on.

Also note it may be CMD.EXE implementation of `echo` that doesn't like the newline -- other programs *may* deal with it as you expect, so it's worth trying on `ffmpeg`.

(**edit:** as Tom notes, windows PowerShell doesn't have the problem that cmd.exe does)

If all you're doing is creating `t.txt` to use as *input* to ffmpeg you can create it directly from PHP instead.

Comment: Thanks. It is valid for *nix systems, but seems Windows doesn't like CRLF and the only way I found is to use PowerShell on Windows which accepts `n as CRLF in arguments. PHP should have shell_exec alternative for Windows based on ShellExecute or something similar. With ShellExecute CRLF is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
shell_exec('echo "Hello \n World" >t.txt');

$ cat t.txt
Hello
 World
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But on Windows it gives `"Hello \nWorld"` in t.txt. How can I do this on Windows too?

Comment: thats because windows considers every thing within " " to be a string since /n is included it outputs it like it is part of the text.