# Why is \r\n not creating a new line?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$txt = "Name: \n" . $_POST["name"] .
"\r\n Company: " . $_POST["company"] .
"\r\nEmail: " . $_POST["email"] .
"\r\nPhone: " . $_POST["phone"] .
"\r\nCategory: " . $_POST["category"] .
"\r\nDescription: " . $_POST["desc"];

echo $txt;
```

and the output is:

> Name: Bob Company: Bob\'s company Email: bob@bob.com Phone: 1231231234 Category: Automation Description: This isn\'t working

With no new lines. Could someone please point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Because you probably look at the html output, so also use html tags, like: `<br>`..

Comment: I'd suggest switch over to ['PHP_EOL`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) instead of "hardcoded" line breaks.

Comment: look at your HTML source - wink - they're there alright.

Comment: `\n` are only for writing to files which will put that under a new line. You're probably wanting to send an email, but didn't choose the right encoding for it. who knows what you *really* want to do here. Show us your real code and the real use for it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol

Answer (score 0):

To break line in HTML use `<br/>`.

Would recommended using `PHP_EOL`.

Here is the link:

[When do I use the PHP constant "PHP_EOL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Comment: I wouldn't have submitted an answer for this. Not till I know exactly what the OP wants to use it for. Plus, it's already been stated in comments and OP isn't responding. Not yet anyway.