# How to add symbol in each end of the line in php?

Tags: php

**Example**

```
$string = "Test Line 1 
Test Line 2 
Test Line 3"; 
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL,"/".PHP_EOL, $string );
```

Actually I am expecting output is

> Test Line 1 \
>
> Test Line 2 \
>
> Test Line 3 \

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I imagine you're having trouble printing the \ because it's escaping the quote. Try `str_replace(PHP_EOL,"\\".PHP_EOL, $string );`

Comment: the php file used is saved with a line ending (say, CRLF) different from the system (osx, *nix) native format (LF), thus replacement doesn't work as expected. check your text editor configuration for that file.

Comment: @Ankh It's wrong slash `/` will not escape anything. Also it's not possible output, because in code you use `/` while expecting to get `\\`

Comment: @Justinas That's the example, look at the expected output...

Comment: Perhaps you should use a backslash ``\`` instead of a slash`/` if you want to have a backslash in your output?

Comment: @Ankh You are right. it will work with your code as expected

Comment: @Ankh It does not work. I've tested in phpfiddle.org

Comment: @Ankh but your code not add \ at the last line

Comment: This answer should meet your requirements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol

Comment: As `PHP_EOL` is platform-dependent, I think, it's problematic to use if the source of the string is unkown. Say the string uses `\r\n` while your platform uses `\n` only. A regular expression, handling both cases whould be more *safe*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**Edited:**

```
<?php
    $string = "Test Line 1 
    Test Line 2 
    Test Line 3"; 
    $str = str_replace(PHP_EOL,"\<br />", $string) . " \\"; 
    echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\\` instead of `"/"`

```
<?php
$string = "Test Line 1 
Test Line 2 
Test Line 3"; 
 $var=str_replace(PHP_EOL,"\\"."</br>", $string ); 
echo $var." \\"; // this append \ in last string
?>
```

Comment: This is the output you would get from this code, `Test Line 1 \ Test Line 2 \ Test Line 3\\`, and this is not the expected output.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul check result in browser console it will show you exact output

Answer (score 0):

If this is just so that you can put the php value into a JS variable, you can just use `json_encode()` which will change the new lines to `\n` for you

```
$string = "Test Line 1 
Test Line 2 
Test Line 3"; 

echo json_encode($string);
// outputs(including quotes) "Test Line 1 \nTest Line 2 \nTest Line 3"
```