# Php Update Text Every Day

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a PHP code to my website so every week the text on the website would update from a stored file like `quotes.txt` I have a PHP code someone gave to me but I need some help I'm not understanding how I would do the html and put this on my website here is the code.

```
$text = file("quotes.txt");       

$search = array ("\r\n", "\r");
$text = str_replace($search, "\n", $text);

$array = explode("\n", $text);

$line = date("z");

echo $array[$line];
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

First than all you will need to check first if you hosting provider allows cron-tab jos, that is, to automatically run a script every x time. If it does then you are half the way. Otherwise the only way to run that script would be by launching it yourself, and might be that is not the idea!

Comment: Hi I was needing to ask i think they do I just needed to know how do i test this code with html?

Answer (score 0):

your question as it stands is very broad, there's a lot of question I'd ask such as is there any HTML in the quotes.txt or is it just content?

What you seem to be implying is that you have a single line from a list of lines that is displayed based on a date formula? So Quotes.txt has 52 lines of text one for each day and then a line number is picked at random?

I want to go through your question one part at a time.

```
$text = file("quotes.txt");
```

It would be better here to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) because that's all you need, the contents not the metadata or filedata.

```
$search = array ("\r\n", "\r");
$text = str_replace($search, "\n", $text);
$array = explode("\n", $text);
```

This part is misleading as the semi-standardisation of line endings (to `\n`) is wasted in the `explode` statement. I would use [`PHP_EOL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) and ignore the string replace.

```
$line = date("z");
```

`z` is the day of the year, however your question is weeks, and that is `W` as the [ISO-8601 week number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (0 to 52) .

```
echo $array[$line];
```

This echo should be the part outputting to your browser, but this will simply output the content rather than wrap it in valid HTML, you'd have to do that your own way, basically you're just dumping data to the browser with no tags, or anything beyond the contents of that line in the array.

So a rewrite:

```
$text = file_get_contents("quotes.txt");  
$text = trim($text); //This removes blank lines so that your 
//explode doesn't get any empty values at the start or the end.     
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$lineNumber = date('W');
```

What this will output is **only** the data in the array line number. You can wrap it in cursory HTML as so:

```
    print "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                     <title>My Page!</title>
                   </head>
           <body>
                <p>";
    echo $array[$lineNumber];
print "</p>
          </body>
     </html>";
```

If you have a standard HTML page already that you want to insert the data into then you can simply `print` or `echo` the value as you have done already and exampled above. You would possibly need to add tags such as `<?php ... ?>` (to open and close the PHP section) and you would also need to save the page as `.php` if it is a `.html` file.

Comment: where would i put the php code and the html can you make it so the echo is surrounded by p tags ?

Comment: try using a tutorial to learn about PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php there are such a wide range of options in answering your question it would be wrong to give you a single answer, as there are many, depending on your preferred method of coding. `print` and `echo` are very similar commands in PHP

Comment: Im getting an error when using this code <?php 
$text = file_get_contents("quotes.txt");  
$text = trim($text); //This removes blank lines so that your 
//explode doesn't get any empty values at the start or the end.     
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$lineNumber = date('s');

  echo "<p>$array[$lineNumber]</p>";
?>

Comment: what does the error say? What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: so now its just displaying numbers randomly everytime, look at this https://gyazo.com/fba5fc414228b1ab2a79bb877642477a thats a gif of what happens everytime i reload the page. My php verson is 5.3.28                               my code is here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44148c3be83cd08dc1b0564491bfbbc09eb5173e