# Open manifest File and Add Text Using PHP

Tags: php

So I am trying to open a manifest File, add a A row of text to last row of text (ex.#Revision Date 21-12-2016), as of now what happens is i get this `#Revision Date 20-12-2016#Revision Date 21-12-2016` all on the same line. instead i would like  this after each time i run the script, to add the the new line under the old line

```
#Revision Date 20-12-2016
#Revision Date 21-12-2016
#Revision Date 22-12-2016
```

I have tried many different solutions like . PHP_EOL, "\n"  here is my script that i have been using

Script

```
<?php
$filename2 = 'newapp/cache.manifest';
$current1 = file_get_contents($filename2);
$current1 .= "John Smith". PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filename2, $current1);
?>
```

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. What OS are you running this under?

Comment: `$line = "john";` and `file_put_contents($filename2, $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` there is no need to `file_get_contents()` first.

Comment: @Xorifelse Even without `FILE_APPEND`, I tested their code and it added it under a new line. I deleted a comment about using that, maybe I shouldn't have.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I guess its just one of those days: "Why isn't my code working!!", while it actually works..

Comment: sorry forgot to add chrome windows

Comment: *"sorry forgot to add chrome windows"* - what do you mean by that? That you're running this under Windows? and using which, xampp, wamp, other? `PHP_EOL` is cross-platform so that should work. Also how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or straight in your browser as `file:///`?

Comment: if you're under windows, then use `"\r\n"` - the `\n` is for Linux only. But I still can't see why `PHP_EOL` would fail you here.

Comment: Ok going to re-edit question as i figured it out what i have done wrong, i didn't realize that txt file would make a difference when i was actually editing a manifest file.  Just figured it was the same and less complicated, so sorry for the confusion, i am going to re-edit question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The only plausible reason is that he echo's the file content to the browser (not checking the source noor the file itself in notepad)

Comment: @Xorifelse I've added my answer below which I feel is what's going on.

Comment: i am not echo file out into screen, i am looking at the file directly.

Comment: since you're using this in a manifest as you said in comments, we need to know how you're using this. Your question IMHO is still unclear.

Comment: @user3015877 did you not try `"\r\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL`? I did write that out in an answer below also.

Comment: sorry was trying out, and yes that did work `$current1 .= 'John Smith'. "\r\n";` thanks so much for yours and everyone's else help, and sorry about the confusion, much appreciated

Comment: @user3015877 I'm glad to hear that the `\r\n` worked for you. I find it rather odd though that the `PHP_EOL` did not work for you, *most bizarre*. You're welcome, *cheers*

Comment: @user3015877 I'm curious; which PHP version are you running this under? the exact version - `PHP_EOL` was introduced in PHP 5.0.2 http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php - if it's lower, than that may very well be why it didn't work.

Comment: This hosting package is currently running PHP Version: 5.6, just to add the original script I post does work properly if it is a txt file.  I was actually updating manifest file and it would not work.  But using `\r\n` does work for manifest file.

Comment: @user3015877 Oh, I see. Therefore the .`manifest` file extension may be the reason because of its extension, and could be a host/server-specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running this under a Windows environment, use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`, since `\n` is for *NIX systems.

However, I can't see why `PHP_EOL` wouldn't work in this instance, since that is cross-platform.

If you're trying to echo this on screen, then that's the reason why it's showing you that in one line.

`\n` or `\r\n` will appear on a new line in the file, as opposed to on screen which is a completely different animal altogether.

So echo on a different line for each, you'd need to use `<br>` or `<p>` tags, or as mentioned in a comment by  Xorifelse `nl2br(file_get_contents($filename2));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FILE_APPEND flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to add to an existing file (also LOCK_EX if you want to ensure nobody else edits the file at the same time).

```
$filename2 = 'newapp/cache.txt';
$new_text = "John Smith\n";
file_put_contents($filename2, $new_text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: sure but that doesn't explain why their code is failing them, where as I tested it on Xampp/Windows which worked fine using `PHP_EOL` which is cross-platform under all OS's

Comment: Well, based on the code that's in the question, the single line result makes sense. They're adding the "John Smith" to the end of their existing file without adding a line break first.

Comment: Even if there isn't a line break at the end of the last entry, it should still create a new one for each new additions; I tested this theory already.

Comment: The result of file_get_contents will just be a string. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if there's no explicit line break at the end of that string, then concatenating another string will not create one.

Comment: I suggest you try their code on your own machine, if you have php etc. installed on your pc. You'll see that what they posted and even under a \*NIX system, it should still work.

Comment: ok i tried the above script and this is what i get `John Smith
John Smith
John Smith
John Smith
John Smith
`

Comment: I am not if this matters as i am going to try now is that the txt file is a manifest file, did not think it matter, but am going to try now

Comment: @user3015877 Are you seriously echoing the data with `echo file_get_contents($filename2)` to see the results in your browser? Check the `txt` file instead or in your browser press `CRTL + U` or `nl2br(file_get_contents($filename2));`

Comment: user3015877 - make sure you have the line breaks in there. fred-ii - i just tested this on my macOS and it works as I described. If the original file has no line break at the end, the resulting text will all be on one line.

Comment: @jackel414 Different OS's will react differently using different end of line syntax. I feel that the question goes deeper than we originally thought. Let's only hope we can find the true reason here ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I agree. Odd that the PHP_EOL wouldn't work (as you mentioned in your answer). I would expect that to be OS agnostic.

Comment: @jackel414 PHP_EOL didn't work on macOS? that is most bizarre. Found this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/128560/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry - I meant that it seemed to not work for OP. It works for me.

Comment: @jackel414 ok. Well... at this point in time, I don't know where to throw myself *lol*. I asked the OP if using `"\r\n"` worked for them or not, but haven't responded anywhere. I did post an answer of my own (no competition on yours here) ;-) so I'll just leave it for now. I can't spend anymore time on something I don't know what I'm dealing with.

Comment: @jackel414 Update: seems the `\r\n` did the trick for them. Why the `PHP_EOL` did not, is the big question.