# PHP fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Tags: php, csv

I have the following code, that I use to read a csv file with CRLF as lines endings

```
if (($fp = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($record = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\r\n")) !== FALSE) {
                if ($row == 0) {
                    $record[0] = $batchHeader;
                }
                $newCsvData[] = $record;
                $row++;
            }
        }
```

When I upload the csv file I get the following error: fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Here is a sample or my csv:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: `"\r\n"`...you have two characters there...

Comment: Try use [PHP_EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol). (I haven't tested if this will work for fgetcsv)

Comment: As mentioned, you can only use 1 character and you're trying to use both a carriage return and line feed.  Just apply the `\r` before the `\n` and use `\n` as the delimiter.

Comment: @RToyota in terms of the .csv, a PHP_EOL will not create a new line so normally, it's not used as a delimiter.  `\n` in a .csv (or any text file) will create a new line which gives .csv files slightly better readability.  As a result, using a PHP_EOL won't do much good (it will also be visible and no new lines will be created).  Although OP is kinda missing the point of .csv files and using a `\n` as a delimiter since it's automatically handled if you use commas as a delimiter and simply iterate over every row.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing it reads `"\r\n"` as your delimiter. Have you tried `fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "|")` ?

It should auto-detect line endings.

[PHP reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in question is the delimiter (field separator), not the row separator. In your case, `|`should be your delimiter. The function will handle line endings itself.

Take a read for more information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php