# The proper use of PHP_EOL and how to get rid of character count when reading a file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a function in which a string of text is written with timestamps to the file "text2.txt", I want each entry to be on a new line, but PHP_EOL does not seem to work for me.The strings simply write on the same line and does not write to a new line for each string.

Could anyone give me some pointers or ideas as to how to force the script to write to a new line every time the function is activated?
Some sort of example would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['sendmsg']))
  {
    writemsg();
  }

  function writemsg()
  {
    $txt = $_POST['tbox'];
    $file = 'text2.txt';
    $str = date("Y/m/d H:i:s",time()) . ":" . $txt;
    file_put_contents($file, $str . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND );
    header("Refresh:0");
  }
?>
```

Also, I want to get rid of the character count on the end of the string when using the below code :

```
<?php
  echo readfile("text2.txt");
?>
```

Is there any way for the character count to be disabled or another way to read the text file so it does not show the character count?

Comment: What operating system is executing the PHP? How are you viewing the file?

Comment: use the nl2br($str) may help.

Comment: @abrar OP isn't writing HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I use the PHP constant "PHP\_EOL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol)

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone give me some pointers or ideas as to how to force the script to write to a new line every time the function is activated? Some sort of example would be highly appreciated.

Given the code you posted I'm pretty sure **newlines** are properly appended to the text lines you are writing to the file.

Try opening the file `text2.txt` on a **text editor** to have a definitive confirmation.

Note that if you insert `text2.txt` as part of a HTML document **newlines** won't cause a line break **in the rendered HTML** by the browser.

You have to turn them into line break tags `<br/>`.

In order to do that simply

```
<?php
    echo nl2br( file_get_contents( "text2.txt" ) );
?>
```

Using `file_get_contents` will also solve your issue with the characters count display.

---

A note about [**readfile**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) you (mis)used in the code in your answer.

Accordind to the documentation

> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.
>
> [...]
>
> Returns the number of bytes read from the file. If an error occurs, **FALSE** is returned and unless the function was called as @readfile(), an error message is printed.

As `readfile` reads a file and **sends the contents to the output buffer** you would have:

```
$bytes_read = readfile( "text2.txt" );
```

**Without** the `echo`.

But in your case you need to operate on the contents of the file (replacing line breaks with their equivalent html tags) so using `file_get_contents` is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

To put new line in text simply put `"\r\n"` (must be in double quotes).
*Please note* that if you try to read this file and output to HTML, all new line (no matter what combination) will be replaced to simple space, because new line in HTML is `<br/>`. Use `nl2br($text)` to convert new lines to `<br/>`'s.

For reading file use `file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: `PHP_EOL` should suffice. In fact, depending on the operating system, it may already be `\r\n`

Comment: Given the file is named `text2.txt`, I doubt OP is having any HTML issues

Comment: @Phil Yes, I know, but problem seems to be deeper, beyond OP question information.