# How to add Line Break for discount text on cart page of Woocommerce on Wordpress in function.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, line-breaks, discount

This is my code below and I've tried \n 
 '\n' '
' but nothing worked. I want to have two lines or paragraphs with First Line and Second Line in the discount line on the cart page

```
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) {
  $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
  $chosen_shipping_no_ajax = $chosen_methods[0];
  if ( 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping_no_ajax, 'local_pickup' ) ) {

    // Define the discount percentage
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.15;
    // Add your discount note to cart
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'First Line (Second line)', 'yourtext-domain') , -$discount );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line');
```

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: i've added .PHP_EOL. but not difference displayed on the webpage but I can see the line break in the code when I inspect the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `PHP_EOL`

- *Source @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol*

> PHP_EOL is ostensibly used to find the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way

```
$cart->add_fee( __( 'First Line' . PHP_EOL . '(Second line)', 'yourtext-domain') , -$discount );
```

---

### Learn more

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/128564/3645650