# How to add a next line space (/r/n) in the php printf statement?

Tags: php

How to add \r\n next to the output: `<div>%s ► %s</div>`

For ex-

```
First output
\r\n
Second output
```

in:

`printf("<div>%s ► %s</div>", $r['bla-bla'], $r['bla-bla']);`

I have tried like:"`<div>%s ► %s</div>\r\n`" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Bear in mind that line breaks have no effect in HTML documents. You may want to use `<br>` instead, jf you're viewing the output in a web page.

Comment: P.s. if you want the line break _between_ the two outputs (I assume %s denotes an output?) then `<div>%s ► %s</div>\r\n` doesn't make sense...surely it would need to be `<div>%s \r\n %s</div>`.

Comment: The output is something like: 101 ► Description. I want a next line after one such output.

Comment: `div`s are block level elements so if you're viewing the output in a browser it will automatically go to to the next line after each div closes, unless you use CSS to alter it. Or are you viewing the raw output in a console or text editor or something? You didn't really explain the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Try `PHP_EOL` like:

```php
<?php
printf("first line" . PHP_EOL . "SECOND line");
```

See also [When do I use the PHP constant “`PHP_EOL`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128560/8740349)